# NASM I cannot access data from the .data section ( DB/DW/DD... )

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Im trying to programming in nasm a x16 toy OS, but can't acess the correct value of DW/DB

When i try to access any .data section value or to be more specific, any DB/DW/DD/DQ value, the program dont gimme the right value, like if DW behave like RESW, i got to put the value with `mov WORD [value_], 0x0100`, to store the wanted value and Nasm dont point any mistakes.

I tryed to implement the correction suggestions but what became most close was this

bootloader.asm:

```
BITS 16

reset:

    xor ax,ax; AH = 0 = Reset floppy disk
    int 0x13;

    mov ax,0x07E0; When we read the sector

    mov es,ax; Set ES with 0x07e0
    xor bx,bx; Offset to read sector to

load_floppy:

    mov ah, 0x2
    mov al, 0x1
    mov ch, 0x0
    mov cl, 0x2
    mov dh, 0x0
    int 0x13

    jmp 0x07E0:0x0000; Jump to 0x7e0:0x0000

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0; complete the bootsector with null
dw 0xAA55; end of bootsector
```

system.asm:

```
BITS 16

    text_string db 'This is my cool new OS!', 0

data: ; i found that code in http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/write-your-own-os.html

    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
    add ax, 288     ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096

    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
    mov ds, ax

main:

    mov si, text_string ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine

    jmp $

print_string:           ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
    mov ah, 0Eh     ; int 10h 'print char' function

.repeat:

    lodsb           ; Get character from string
    cmp al, 0
    je .done        ; If char is zero, end of string
    int 10h         ; Otherwise, print it
    jmp .repeat

.done:
    ret
```

this gimme a crazy output with 13 chars from the extended ascii and one of these is a smile emoticon

this code gimme the correct output but just if i use only the bootloader.asm:

```
BITS 16

text_string db 'Its ok here!', 0

start:

    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
    add ax, 288     ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096

    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
    mov ds, ax

    mov si, text_string ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine

    jmp $           ; Jump here - infinite loop!

    print_string:           ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
        mov ah, 0Eh     ; int 10h 'print char' function

.repeat:

    lodsb           ; Get character from string
    cmp al, 0
    je .done        ; If char is zero, end of string
    int 10h         ; Otherwise, print it
    jmp .repeat

.done:
    ret

times 510-($-$$) db 0;
dw 0xAA55;
```

Comment: You likely forgot to set up `DS` properly.

Comment: how i can do it?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you are doing ... but generally speaking set `DS` to correspond to the segment where you load your 2nd sector in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the BIOS jumps to your code:

- DL will contain the "BIOS device number" for whatever storage device you booted from.
- all other general purpose registers are left set to uninitialized ("random") values
- all segment registers are left set to uninitialized ("random") values
- the stack (`SS:SP`) will be left set to something that should be valid (in case an IRQ occurs before you set up your stack); but you have no idea where (and you're going to want to load more data into memory and can't risk overwriting your stack when you do)
- CS:IP will also be left set to undefined values; except that whatever they are will work out to the same 0x00007C00 physical address (e.g. could be 0x0000:0x7C00, could be 0x07C0:0x0000, and could be something much less likely like 0x0700:0x0C00)
- the flags might be anything. This usually doesn't matter until you use an instruction that depends on the direction flag (e.g. "rep stosw").
- your .BSS section will not be filled with zeros like you might be used to
- segmentation will confuse you and using non-zero segments will lead to bugs. To use zero segments you have to use `org 0x7C00`.

To fix all that, you need to do something like:

```
    org 0x7C00

    ; More stuff here if you want...

main:
    xor ax,ax
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    cli                     ;Only for 8086
    mov ss,ax
    mov sp,0x7C00
    sti
    cld
    jmp far 0x0000:.here     ;Optional in theory, to set CS
.here:
    mov di,_BSS_START
    mov cx,_BSS_END - _BSS_START
    rep stosb                ;Fill BSS with zeros

    mov [bootDeviceNumber],dl


    ; More stuff here if you want... (at least a `jmp $` so you don't start executing data)
```

Comment: Note that the code in the question is in the 2nd sector, not the bootsector. Presumably the bootsector loads it.

Comment: in the final .img the .BSS is ok, just zeros, the problem is just with the "Defined" values that dont trully define, just reserve the bytes, i tryed with a simple code with no second sector load, and the problem still here ( i will put the code in question ).

Comment: @Jester: D'oh, I missed that (and wasn't expecting it - most people learn about things like setting segment registers when their 1st sector keeps crashing).

Comment: @PatrickSant: Be careful to avoid "works by accident" (e.g. being lucky and finding that the BIOS happened to leave zeros in the memory area you're using for BSS) - you can guarantee that luck doesn't last. ;-)

Comment: i see what u're talking about and i'll try don make that mistake( thanks ), but i did test the variables at .bss, and they are working fine, i think the problem is in my nasm( and yasm ) or syntax but the syntax looks fine to me.

Comment: Since you have not shown complete code we can only guess, but as I said, you are likely loading your 2nd sector somewhere in memory but don't set `DS` accordingly.

Comment: the final code that i posted, is the full code at test.asm, besides this i got only the makefile that i will post too.

Comment: Now for THAT bootsector code Brendan's answer applies. You need to do `xor ax,ax; mov ds,ax`.

Comment: I correct a piece of the code using almost this that you wrote, but just work if i dont use `ORG` or `SECTION`. and if i just use the bootloader.asm